# Passing dynamic functor to stl

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, functor

I am relatively new to c++ and this is my very first post, so be gentle ;-)

I understand how to pass function pointers or function objects, like many stl functions require. It is unclear to me how to use this in combination with inheritance.

Specifically I would like to call a stl function with several functors that inherit from a base functor. I have not found any relevant remarks or best practices on this topic. Here a simplified code snippet:

```
struct generator{
  virtual int operator()() = 0;
  virtual ~generator(){};
};

struct A : public generator{
  int operator()();
};

struct B : public generator{
  int operator()();
};

int main()
{
  auto v = std::vector<std::array<int, 500>>(2);
  std::array<std::shared_ptr<generator>, 2> functors = {{std::make_shared<A>(),
                                                         std::make_shared<B>()}};
  for (size_t i = 0; i < functors.size(); ++i)
    std::generate(std::begin(v[i]), std::end(v[i]),
                  *(functors[i]));
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this gives:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra test_stackoverflow.cpp 
test_stackoverflow.cpp:25:5: error: no matching function for call to 'generate'
    std::generate(std::begin(v[i]), std::end(v[i]),*(functors[i]));
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5003:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution
      failure [with _ForwardIterator = int *, _Generator = generator]: parameter type 'generator' is an abstract class
    generate(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
```

Yes the type of *(functors[i]) is generator. Which will not allow for dynamic access to A::operator() and B::operator(). I understand how to (rudamentally) solve this. e.g.

```
std::generate(std::begin(v[i]), std::end(v[i], 
              [&]{ return functors[i]->operator()(); };
```

However this seems rather obfuscated and I'm looking for a clearer way to achieve my goals.

How does one usually pass such dynamic functors. Or if this is frowned upon, what is the best alternative?

Any help or suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you may already know, is that `std::generate` takes the generator by value. To pass a polymorphic object, you must pass by reference.

And there is a solution for exactly this kind of problem in c++11 (besides the lambda option, which is still more elegant than what we had before c++11, I believe). The solution is [std::ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref). It returns a reference wrapper that can be passed by value.

This should work for you:

```
std::generate(std::begin(v[i]), std::end(v[i]),
              std::ref(*(functors[i])));
```

The reason why you can pass reference wrappers as a functor, is that they implement the [operator()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%28%29)

Comment: Also, `std::function`

Comment: Confirmed, can pass `std::ref` to algorithms.  Did not know that.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db815184c44240ad

Comment: I'll be honest. I'd never heard of std::ref. So thank you for that. Are you of the opinion that a lambda is to be prefered over this, and if so why?

Comment: @APevar The lambda is great if you need to capture something else besides the functor, but since you don't, I think `std::ref` is the perfect fit for the problem.

Comment: I've looked at the semantics concerning std::ref. I (think I) understand how this can be useful occasionally. How often is this actually used in production code? Is std::ref more practically relevant than a lambda capture, and if so when would this be the case?

Comment: @APevar I haven't reviewed a lot of "production code" in c++ so I wouldn't know. But I see no reason why I wouldn't use `std::ref` besides requiring c++11. Then again, it is also implemented in boost and lamdas require c++11 as well. The pre c++11 non-boost solution would be to define your own type which wraps a reference to the type of functor that you want and implements `operator()`. All these 3 solutions are essentially the same thing except one is a custom type, another is an anonymous type (lamda) and the third is an instance of a class template (`std::reference_wrapper`).

Comment: also, is this the standard behaviour? Is it usual for stl functions to make copies of passed functors or similar? Why would the designers have decided to make this decision?

Comment: @APevar: You can always implement *reference semantics* on top of an interface that passes by value (`std::ref` --which is simpler in C++11, but you can implement something similar in C++98 with a bit more typing), but not the other way around.

Comment: @APevar you may be interested in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196345/passing-functor-object-by-value-vs-by-reference-c