# Why do stl algorithms take callables by value?

Tags: c++, pass-by-value, stl-algorithm

I stumbled upon this while trying something equivalent to

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct pred { //not copyable
    pred () {}
    bool operator()(int) const { return false; }
    pred( pred && ) {}
};

int main () {
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> b{};
    auto p = pred{};
    //std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), p); // this fails
    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), std::move(p));
}
```

see https://godbolt.org/z/wDvO3K

Why can stl algorithms not accept universal references for the "operations"?

PS: Apologies if this is a duplicate, I would be surprised if it isn't..

Comment: `std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), pred());`

Comment: Relevant/duplcate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803927/why-does-stdfind-iffirst-last-p-not-take-predicate-by-reference

Comment: well sure @DimChtz, but that was not the question ^^

Comment: so, @StoryTeller, would you say that universal references would make sense nowadays?

Comment: @kawillzocken - If it was designed from scratch today, maybe. But given the changes to the core language, there is practically nothing lost by keeping it a value.

Comment: An extract of the answer from the linked post which explains the reference part: "So up to c++11, we don't really have an alternative. A pass by value would be better than a reference. With the new standard, we may revise our approach. To support rvalues, we may add an rvalue reference overload.

By passing a value, the caller has the choice in how to create it, and for prvalues, in c++17, it's practically free. If the caller so desires, they can provide referential semantics explicitly. So nothing is lost, and I think much is gained in terms of simplicity of usage and API design"