# c++ how to use universal reference in a function multiple times

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

This question is migrated from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284030/c-how-to-use-universal-reference-in-a-function-multiple-times) since it is marked off-topic over there

I need to pass an rvalue-reference (temporary) as a parameter to a function taking unversal reference. It be used multiple times inside. Each function calling it accepts rvalue-reference as special overload. My question is how we should forward the parameter.

Following is an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Game {
    Game(const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    Game(std::string&& n) : name(std::move(n)) {}
    std::string name;
};

struct Student {
    // constructor: not important for the discussion
    Student(const string& n) : name(n){}
    Student(string&& n) : name(std::move(n)) {}

    // play has overloaded for several different types
    void play(const std::string& game) {
        cout << name << " plays |" << game << "| (L)"<< endl;
        games.emplace_back(game);
    }
    void play(std::string&& game) {
        cout << name << " plays |" << game << "| (R)"<< endl;
        games.emplace_back(std::move(game));
    }
    void play(const Game& game) {
        cout << name << " plays |" << game.name << "| (L)"<< endl;
        games.emplace_back(game);
    }
    void play(Game&& game) {
        cout << name << " plays |" << game.name << "| (R)"<< endl;
        games.emplace_back(std::move(game));
    }
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Game> games;
};

struct Class {
    // construct: not important here. Did not overload for &&
    Class(const vector<string>& names) {
        for (auto name : names) {
            students.emplace_back(std::move(name));
        }
    }
    
    // perfect forwarding works nice
    template <typename G>
    void play_by_first(G&& game) {
        if (students.size() == 0) return;
        students[0].play(std::forward<G>(game));
    }

    // this is relevant part. 
    // How to code for a generic game of type G and 
    // game might or might not be temporary
    template <typename G>
    void play(G&& game) {
        for (auto& student : students) {
            student.play(std::forward<G>(game)); // <--- how to change this line
        }
    }
    vector<Student> students;
};

int main() {
    // normal here
    Class grade1({"alice"});
    grade1.play("football");
    grade1.play(Game("basketball"));

    cout << endl;
    // Charlie has nothing to play
    Class grade2({"bob", "Charlie"});
    grade2.play(std::string{"football"});
    grade2.play(Game("basketball"));
}
```

[try run](https://godbolt.org/z/95o9rE7j3)

As you can see, when we only need to use it once, as in `play_by_first`, perfect forwarding (`std::forward`) will be the ultimate solution. However, when it used multiple times, the rvalues will be invalid after the first call.

Is there a standard way in modern c++ to handle this? I still wanna to have some optimization for temporaries. I hope there is some standard solution to utilize this.

I also looked into the std library, tried to learn from implementations such as `find_if` where the predicator can be an rvalue reference and will be called multiple times. Howerver, it does not take [universal reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75773610/7026980), and cannot handle rvalue references specially.

Comment: You can only forward a universal reference once. If you need to use it many times, juat use it without forwarding. You can forward it the last time you use it.

Comment: If you need mulitple copies of something then you need to copy it to get mulitple copies.

Answer (score 1):

An rvalue reference is allowed to be used only once.

What you can do is make a `move` for the last call and a `copy` for all previous ones. Unfortunately, this complicates the code a bit.

```
#include <span>

template <typename G>
void play(G&& game) {
    if(students.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    for (auto& student : std::span(students.begin(), students.end() - 1)) {
        student.play(game);
    }

    students.back().play(std::forward<G>(game));
}
```

There is currently no generally suitable function for this. But of course you can write one:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename F, typename E, typename T>
constexpr void invoke_for_any(F f, std::vector<E>& vec, T&& v) {
    if(vec.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end() - 1, [&](E& e){ f(e, v); });

    f(vec.back(), std::forward<T>(v));
}

// ...

template <typename G>
void play(G&& game) {
    invoke_for_any(
        []<typename T>(Student& student, T&& game){
            student.play(std::forward<T>(game));
        }, students, std::forward<G>(game));
}
```

It is important here that the lambda function is a template that can receive the second argument as lvalue or rvalue reference. The function `invoke_for_any` calls the overload for rvalue references for the last element if it has received an rvalue reference itself. In all other cases the overload for lvalue references is called.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an rvalue reference to a function, you're implicitly giving that function permission to invalidate it, so passing the same rvalue reference to a function several times in a loop is going to be a problem.  If you don't want the function to invalidate your reference, pass an lvalue reference instead.

The previous answer gives you a way to copy game every time except the last and the move it the last time, which is the closest you can get to what you asked.

I think it's much cleaner, however, for `Class::play()` to take an lvalue reference instead of a universal reference and call the lvalue reference overload of `Student::play()`.

`Student::play(Game&&)` implicitly says "when a Student plays a game, the game is consumed."  That definition of `play()`, however, is inconsistent with the idea of having multiple Students playing the same game.

It sounds like this is going too far to avoid copying, but if multiple students are playing the same game, there's no avoiding it.  If Game is so expensive to copy that these move operations are worth the trouble, could you change the design so that `Student::play()` and `Class::play()` take `Game*` instead?