# universal reference for predicate in std::find_if()?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

`std::find_if`'s UnaryPredicate is by value. Why cannot we have it by universal reference? i.e.

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
InputIt find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
                 UnaryPredicate&& p );
```

Is it mostly for historical reasons, or is there reason to prefer pass by value over universal reference in this case even with c++11?

Related questions:
[Passing functor object by value vs by reference (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196345/passing-functor-object-by-value-vs-by-reference-c), 
[Why does std::find_if(first, last, p) not take predicate by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803927/why-does-stdfind-iffirst-last-p-not-take-predicate-by-reference)

Comment: Well, the interior of the algorithm is allowed to make copies so taking by reference could be misleading.

Comment: And changing that might break old code, so I would say historical reasons.